# findNavController().navigate(direction) does not work for Over ride methods of Interstitial.setAdListener but it works for on click listener (Android)

Tags: android, controller, navigation, androidx

Here is the code in onAdClosed or onAdFailed method navigation is not working but in else part of the IF Statement it works

```
void NavigateFragmentTo(final View v, final int id) {
            //Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(id);
            if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        super.onAdClosed();
                        Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(id);
                        Toast.makeText(app, "closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        RequestInterstitial();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                        super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                        Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(id);
                        RequestInterstitial();
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(id);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please answer to my question.. any one ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to place a delay from when your callback completes to when you try to navigate. It seems that the Navigation component still needs time before it can actually navigate in some scenarios.

Add a delay to something like below

```
mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    super.onAdClosed();
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
                        Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(id);
                    }, 500);
                    Toast.makeText(app, "closed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    RequestInterstitial();
                }

                @Override
                public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                    super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(() -> {
                        Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(id);
                    }, 500);
                    RequestInterstitial();
                }
            });
```